Multiline string interpolation in bicep not working
I have a problem inserting a variable into a multiline string using Bicep.
What works:
I have this param:
param fallbackResourceId string
inserted into a big json multiline string like this:
  "fallbackResourceIds": [
    "${fallbackResourceId}"
  ],

This works an evaluates to the value when the resource is deployed. However, I also have this variable (also tried as param):
param sourceDataCloudRoleName string
param sourceDataOperationName string
var sourceQuery1 = 'traces\r\n| extend prop_syncTableRowIds_array = parse_json(customDimensions.prop__syncRowIds)\r\n| mv-expand prop_syncRowIds_array\r\n| where tostring(prop_syncTableRowIds_array) contains {SyncTableRowId}\r\n| where cloud_RoleName =~ "${sourceDataCloudRoleName}" and operation_Name =~ "${sourceDataOperationName}"'

This is inserted as follows:
{
            "type": 3,
            "content": {
              "version": "KqlItem/1.0",
              "query": "${sourceQuery1}",
              "size": 0,
              "title": "Search by \"SyncRowId\"",
              "timeContextFromParameter": "TimeRange",
              "queryType": 0,
              "resourceType": "microsoft.insights/components"
            },
            "name": "query - 1"
          },

However, here the workbook says that the parameter is not assigned.

My problem was using string interpolation in a multiline string. This is not advised by Microsoft. Instead I am using the replace function, which is not as 'pretty' but does the job,
